# How do I create a NotFoundRoute component using "react-router"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How do I create a NotFoundRoute component using "react-router": "^1.0.0-rc3" ? Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here please?

```
import { NotFoundRoute } from 'react-router';
console.log(NotFoundRoute); //undefined
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NotFoundRoute` was removed from 1.0.0-rc3, instead you just use a `Route` with a catch-all pattern.

Read the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/d28036b97e1e991b2cf502a108673303ac5e0149/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#notfound-route).